# Many classes/interfaces with general project template

Tags: spring, hibernate, templates, jsf-2

I am looking for a general project template to build a web applications with the following technologies: JSF2, Spring3 and Hibernate4

I found an [article](http://www.onlinetechvision.com/?p=566) that proposes a template but I hesitated beacause for each table in my database I need 5 classes/interfaces:

- 2 interfaces (dao + service)
- 2 classes for implementations
- 1 bean

so is it normal? can someone help with a better architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build the architecture on top of the Spring Data JPA module. That would leave you with one class for the entity and one interface (under normal circumstances) for the repository.

For more information take a look at the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/).

**Shortened Example:**

Spring config:

```
<!-- Directory to scan for repository classes -->
<jpa:repositories
   base-package="x.y.z.repositories" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  <property name="jpaDialect">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
      <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
      <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String name;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {

  public List<Product> findByName(String name);

}
```

In order to use the repository, you simply need to inject it:

```
@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you include CGLib as a dependency, you can get rid of the interfaces. You won't need them unless you have different implementations of your services from the beginning. Only introduce them if they're really necessary (1:1 Service:ServiceImpl is an anti pattern if you ask me).

Hibernates/JPAs `EntityManager` is already a generic CRUD DAO, so you don't have to create a DAO for every entity. Introduce them as soon as they are necessary and use `EntityManager` within your service until then.

Disclaimer: This is a lean approach to Java EE, very close to what Adam Bien recommends in his book Java EE Patterns. We adapted this for spring and it works fine so far.

Great question by the way, java folks often forget to ask themselfs "do we really need this?".